# C# Converting String to Int from textbox

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to convert a string from a textbox into an int but every googled answer I've found still seems to bring back the same error of;

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

my code is simply:

```csharp
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAge.Text))
    {
        txtAge.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Age cannot be blank");
    }
    else if(age < 0 || age > 100)
    {
        txtAge.Clear();
        MessageBox.Show("Age must be within rage 0-100");
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated as I feel like this is a simple error to fix but I've been looking at it for hours now going in circles

Comment: And what example input gives this error?

Comment: It would make a lot more sense if the `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAge.Text))` validation block came _before_ the `Parse` command...otherwise there's a danger you'll try to parse an empty string into an integer (which will fail with exactly the error you've mentioned). Clearly if you're going to try and validate that the data is correct/complete, you need to do that before you attempt to use said data, otherwise it's a bit pointless!

Comment: The only other thing that would cause said error is inputting non-integer and non-whitespace data into the textbox. Obviously, we don't know what value you tested it with. P.S. you can always use the `TryParse` method instead, which will test the validity of the data without needing the extra `if`, and will also account for other problematic input data, as well as just emptiness. (Whitespace is not, by itself, actually a problem btw, as long as the string also contains one valid integer - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/XWjRml.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to see something more like:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int age;
    if (Int32.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age))
    {
        if (age >= 0 && age <= 100)
        {

            // ... do something with "age" in here ...
            
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Age must be within range 0-100");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Age. Please enter a valid Age.");
    }
}
```